# How to copy a file with scp via another server

Tags: linux, scp

I have three machines. The local machine L, Server1 A, Server2 B. 
L is able to connect to A 
A is able to connect to B 
L **is not** able to connect to  B

I want to copy a file from L to B without taking the extra step to login on A for coppying the data.

Is that possible with scp? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L **is not** able to connect to B, but is B able to connect to L? You didn't say, but I will assume no.

If A is your only way to communicate between B and L then you will definitely have to log in to A at some point. And also, the data will flow through A one way or another (which might be important if A is on a slow connection).

You can establish an SSH tunnel through A in a couple of different ways to get from L to B. For example:

```
# From L
ssh -L 2222:B:22 -Nf A
```

Now add the following configuration in `~/.ssh/config` on L as a convenience for connecting to B through the tunnel:

```
Host B
    HostName localhost
    HostKeyAlias B
    Port 2222
```

Then you can connect to B through the tunnel:

```
scp file B:
```

There are other options for setting up this tunnel, including tools to automatically establish the tunnel in the background.